# Is there a reference for the tate construction being lax monoidal?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I know that the functor on spectra sending $X$ to $X^{tC_p}$ is lax monoidal.  I am looking for a reference, ideally as early as possible historically, for this fact.

Answer (score 1):

This can be found in the work of Nikolaus--Scholze https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01799.pdf.  See section 3.

Comment: Thanks Allen!  I would still like to know if there is an earlier reference